# No me trae datos SQL a mi programa en c#

Tags: c#

como andan? Estoy queriendo hacer un login en c#, tengo una tabla **Usuario** con los siguientes atributos:

**id (int primary key)
username (varchar)
password (varchar)**

En la clase donde intento conectarme a la base de datos, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog = Sicif; Integrated Security = True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(btnUsuario.Text))
            {
                ** ACA ES PARA VER SI NO SE COLOCARON DATOS EN LOS CAMPOS. **
            }
            else
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string sql = "select username, password from usuario where username = @username AND password = @pass";
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", btnUsuario.ToString().Trim());
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", btnContra.ToString().Trim());
                SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();

                if (leer.Read()) ***(NUNCA ENTRA EN ESTE IF. PORQUE NO SE OBTIENEN DATOS.)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("sisii");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos.");
                }
                conexion.Close();
            } 
        }
    }
```

**Siempre me sale el MessageBox "Datos incorrectos". No encuentro error en el SqlConnection. Esta todo correcto.

**La consulta la probe en SQL server y da un resultado.

**Me da la sensación de que tengo el error en el "Data Source=."
** Agrego captura de SQL SERVER.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y sera porque nadie cumple con ese usuario y ese pass? el codigo parece estar correcto (a excepcion de que la clave no esta encriptada!!!)

Comment: @gbianchi Si que los cumple! En sql server ejecute ese Query y efectivamente lo hay.

Comment: que query? con que datos? que el query funcione no quiere decir que en tu app devuelva datos.. lo ejecutaste con los mismos datos? si leer viene vacio, es porque no esta encontrando registros para tu consulta...

Comment: **select username, password from usuario where username = @username AND password = @pass** Es el que me refiero.

Comment: hacer un select funciona? lo probaste? de esa forma verificas que ande la conexion

Comment: coloca la direccion de tu sql en la cadena de conexion.

Comment: where username = '@username' AND password =' @pass'   ---agrega comillas a tus parametros para que sean cadenas de texto en la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta, en que no estas pasando los valores correctos, en los parámetros de la consulta. Cuando haces esto `btnUsuario.ToString()` devuelves informacion sobre el objeto *no el valor*.

En cambio deberias pasar `btnUsuario.Text.Trim()`.

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", btnUsuario.Text.Trim());
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", btnContra.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración!!! funcionó.